# How to identify that whether the internet connection is IPv4 or IPv6 for ios app through swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ipv4

I am working on a IOS app where i  want some part of the app to be functional on IPv4 connections only. How can i identify whether i am connected to IPv4 or IPv6 through swift programming language.

Comment: I don't think Apple will let you do that. They require IPv6 support in all apps since last year.

Comment: @SanderSteffann my app works fine on ipv6. Its just one function that i would want should trigger when the user is on ipv4. Isn't their any method to fetch ip address and see if its 32 bit or 128bit?

Comment: It depends on what you want, because when connected to an IPv6-only network you will get an 128-bit IPv6 address even for IPv4 services. Looking at the address will only be useful when you want to know the protocol used from the client. What reaches the server might be different.